# Updating a parent object's reference fields from values on a child object in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I am trying to update some values on a parent record when an end user submits a child record. There's some conditional logic I want to build in there too, but trying to get a basic understanding of the structure I need to go with before I start doing that. I've got it all in the trigger but I think I need to break it out into a class and call it. I'm not a programmer by trade, so please do not hesitate to point out where I'm going wrong. I've pieced together the code based on my experience and what I've found online.

```
trigger applicationFeedbackToApp on ApplicationFeedback__c (after insert, after update)
{
    Map<Id,E_Opportunity__c> parentApps = new Map<Id,E_Opportunity__c>();
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

    if(ApplicationFeedback__c.Results__c != null)
    {
         for (ApplicationFeedback__c childObj:trigger.new)
         {
             listIds.add(childObj.E_Opportunity__c);
         }

        parentApps = new Map<Id, ApplicationFeedback__c> (
        [
        SELECT Id
        ,Earned__c
        ,POINTS__c
        ,
        (
        SELECT ApplicationFeedback__c.Application__c
        ,ApplicationFeedback__c.Earned__c
        ,ApplicationFeedback__c.OVERALL_POINTS__c
         FROM ApplicationFeedback__c
         )
         FROM E_Opportunity__c WHERE Id IN :listIds
         ]
         );

         for (ApplicationFeedback__c feed : trigger.new)
         {
            E_Opportunity__c myParentApp = parentApps.get(feed.Application__c);
            myParentApp.Earned__c = feed.Earned__c;
            myParentApp.POINTS__c = feed.POINTS__c;
         }

    }
    update parentApps.values();
}
```

I wanted to get some feedback before I test it out. Normally, I'd handle this in process builder but some managed packages are causing us to hit a SOQL query error (101 queries) and I can't really troubleshoot with a managed package, so I'm trying to see if a trigger might be able to be used more efficiently.

Am I going about this in the right way or really overthinking it?

Comment: That query formatting is painful.

Comment: Sorry! Good to know I am formatting incorrectly! I'm more used to SQL and sometimes the custom object fields can get really really long. Will definitely revise :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this trigger definitely doesn't compile, but it also avoids some key errors. It looks like you've relied on some resources that do bulkification correctly, which is great.

I would suggest working with this trigger in a sandbox using the Developer Console. You have some syntax errors that you may want immediate feedback on to fix, some of which I will note below.

In parallel with that, I would recommend working through some Apex/trigger-related Trailhead modules. You're definitely on the right track with what you've put together so far, and a little more work on language fundamentals will get you past not being a programmer by trade.

The following is not exhaustive, but hopefully will point to a few issues to start fixing in the Developer Console.

```
trigger applicationFeedbackToApp on ApplicationFeedback__c (after insert, after update)
{
    Map<Id,E_Opportunity__c> parentApps = new Map<Id,E_Opportunity__c>();
```

You don't need to create a new object here, because you'll initialize it below.

```
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

    if(ApplicationFeedback__c.Results__c != null)
```

While this line will compile (thanks to Adrian for pointing this out), but it doesn't do anything useful and is always `true`. The compiler will read it as a reference to an `SObjectField`, which is never `null`. I won't make a recommendation because I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do here.

If the objective is to do some filtering on each object in the trigger set, this condition should go *inside* the `for` loops over `Trigger.new`.

```
    {
         for (ApplicationFeedback__c childObj:trigger.new)
         {
             listIds.add(childObj.E_Opportunity__c);
         }

        parentApps = new Map<Id, ApplicationFeedback__c> (
```

This `Map` is typed incorrectly. You're performing a `E_Opportunity__c` query, so you need a `Map<Id, E_Opportunity__c>`.

```
        [
        SELECT Id
        ,Earned__c
        ,POINTS__c
        ,
        (
        SELECT ApplicationFeedback__c.Application__c
        ,ApplicationFeedback__c.Earned__c
        ,ApplicationFeedback__c.OVERALL_POINTS__c
         FROM ApplicationFeedback__c
         )
         FROM E_Opportunity__c WHERE Id IN :listIds
         ]
         );
```

Kudos for correctly using a `Map` and a bulkified query. This is the correct pattern to use for this type of trigger. However, you don't use the subquery data (`SELECT ApplicationFeedback__c.Application__c, ApplicationFeedback__c.Earned__c, ApplicationFeedback__c.OVERALL_POINTS__c FROM ApplicationFeedback__c)`. You can remove it to increase your performance, unless you plan to extend this trigger to do some kind of calculation across all of the children of each `E_Opportunity__c`.

Make sure you have the right relationship name from your lookup or master-detail field in your subquery - it is often *not* the name of the child object.

```
         for (ApplicationFeedback__c feed : trigger.new)
         {
            E_Opportunity__c myParentApp = parentApps.get(feed.Application__c);
```

Unless this is a master-detail relationship, you should check whether `myParentApp` is `null` here. Otherwise, you'll get a `NullPointerException` if an `ApplicationFeedback__c` has no parent.

```
            myParentApp.Earned__c = feed.Earned__c;
            myParentApp.POINTS__c = feed.POINTS__c;
```

Is your ultimate objective to modify these fields in another fashion, or just to overwrite them? If the latter, you can even get away without querying the objects at all. As it stands, you don't use the previous values from `myParentApp`, so you technically don't need to query the field values.

```
         }

    }
    update parentApps.values();

}
```

You're also on the right track to be thinking about factoring this logic into a static handler class using a trigger framework. There is a lot of material available on that subject both on Stack Exchange and elsewhere, but I'd get this trigger running in a sandbox before tackling that.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely use this as a reference. I've got this on a sandbox, definitely never move anything into prod without extensive testing. Will go through suggested modules. Thanks again!